# Facebook POST callback

Tags: facebook, sdk

I have a Facebook "Like" button, I placed it in my site, I can easily detect if someone click on the "Like":

```
// DETECT LIKE
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You LIKED My Page');
    }
);
```

Right after he "Like" my page, a small flying window will be opened by the button so the user could also "Post" something about my page on his wall.

I looked all around, I can't see anyway to detect while a user "Post" a thing on his wall from my "Like" button, is there anyway for doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is one way. If you saved the user's ID and object ID (this kind of "Like" is done by OG) you can grab all og.likes from this user `FB.api('/USER_ID/og.likes', function(response) {
  <iterate through response to find specified object ID and user's post message will be under "message" field>
});`

Try it here: [Facebook OG explorer og.likes](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fog.likes)

GL!

Comment: You won’t have the user’s id unless they explicitly connected to your app … a thing you normally try to avoid when just using a like button.

Comment: Yes, I need it do be done without Auth, since it's possible and users may feel not OK to let their user connect to my app.

Comment: If they might not feel ok connecting to your app, they would probably not feel ok if you try to track when they share something using the like button. The fact that you get an event for users "Liking" something can be helpful, but I would suggest creating an app if you want to do more than that.

Answer (score -1):

Why not analyse the response from the post action?

```
FB.ui('/me/feed', {method: 'feed'}, function (response){
    if (response.post_id){
        // Something was posted by the user
    } else {
        // Nothing was posted
    }
});
```